# Endian Convertion for structures without knowing data type(s)

Tags: c++, endianness

Currently, I tend to avoid using floating point variables when sending data.
The reason for the same is that when I send packets from say a linux PC to a windows PC, due to the endian conversion, I find the data to no longer be readable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945186/5906375

My current code structure converts the data from one endian format to the other before figuring out the packet structure. 
Basically something like this :

```
swapEndianFormat(&input);
messageId = getMessageId(input);
switch(messageId)
{
    case "......":
    ...

}
```

Anyways, so my current function works well for all data types except floating point.

Also, while I have found functions for swapping for floating point variables, I am looking for a generic function where I could just pump the byteArray of the structure and get the converted data which supports unsigned short, int as well as float. That or could someone confirm if it is even possible.

Thanks

Comment: A generic function is not possible. A 4-byte input should be converted differently if it represents a single 32-bit integer (swap bytes 0 and 3, and 1 and 2) vs two 16-bit integers (swap bytes 0 and 1, and 2 and 3). So you need to know the layout of the structure you are converting.

Comment: Okay thanks. I was considering the same, but I needed to confirm it.