# C++ Portable Floating-Point Bit Representation?

Tags: c++, floating-point, portability, ieee-754, bit-representation

Is there a C++ Standards compliant way to determining the structure of a 'float', 'double', and 'long double' at compile-time ( or run-time, as an alternative )?

If I assume `std::numeric_limits< T >::is_iec559 == true` and `std::numeric_limits< T >::radix == 2`, I suspect the is possible by the following rules:

- first X-bits are the significand.
- next Y-bits are the exponent.
- last 1-bit is the sign-bit.

with the following expressions vaguely like:

- `size_t num_significand_bits = std::numeric_limits< T >::digits;`
- `size_t num_exponent_bits = log2( 2 * std::numeric_limits< T >::max_exponent );`
- `size_t num_sign_bits = 1u;`

except I know

- `std::numeric_limits< T >::digits` includes the "integer bit", whether or not the format actually explicitly represents it, so I don't know how to programmatically detect and adjust for this.
- I'm guessing `std::numeric_limits< T >::max_exponent` is always `2^(num_exponent_bits)/2`.

**Background**:  I'm trying to overcome two issues portably:

- set/get which bits are in the significand.
- determine where the end of 'long double' is so I know not to read the implicit padding bits that'll have uninitialized memory.

Comment: I just saw [Question 10620601](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620601/portable-serialisation-of-ieee754-floating-point-values) which uses a seemingly Posix header `ieee754.h` that define structs with bit-field specifiers for everything.  I like that idea, but I'm unsure if that's really portable.

Comment: `Portable Floating-Point Bit Representation?` Yes, the ASCII representation would be portable to any language and any OS. I believe you might have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you trying to do?\

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking in the solution-space of my already decomposed problem.
I want to set and test the payload of a signaling-nan; I want to set and use a signaling-nan as a "null value" for floating-point numbers; however, I'd like to distinguish it from other NaNs produced by the system otherwise.  `nan(char const*)` exists only for quiet-nan, and payload format is not portable.  I need to do "equality testing", but obviously `operator==` for any NaN on either side returns false, so I have to test the underlying binary representation, while avoiding `long double`'s uninitialized packing-bits.

Comment: Why is the packing bits of a concern?

Comment: @MatsPetersson `operator==` can't compare all floating-point values, namely qNaN and sNaN.

Comment: So, basically, you want NaN == NaN to return true? How about `if (isnan(a) && isnan(b)) return true;`?

Comment: I want that and more; I want `isnan(a) && isnan(b) && ( significand(a) == significand(b) )`.

Comment: And you want this to work on IBM mainframes, PC's with SSE and x87 fpu, DEC Alpha, microcontrollers made by some unknown Taiwan company, and everything else, yes? I think you might just as well try come up with the answer to world starvation - in fact, that's probably a lot easier.... :)

Comment: @CharlesLWilcox: what is this "payload" for? Are you sending the numbers to another machine? or saving it to a file? Or is this an IPC in the same system? Why can't you just use a real NULL value, or use a separate field to indicate nullness, or use `std::numeric_limits<float>::max();` or `std::numeric_limits<float>::min();` as your marker value? Relying on the bit pattern of floating point value is always going to be non-portable because IIRC C++ standard does not define the bit representation of floating point numbers.

Comment: @LieRyan The "payload" of the sNaN is to distinguish it from other sNaNs other code could generate.  I can't use "a real NULL", since this is not a pointer, but the primitive floating-point value itself; all I can do is use a specific value to represent the "null value".  NaN's are effectively designed to represent a "null", "invalid", or "indeterminate" floating-point values.

Comment: @LieRyan  Since there is no standard way of creating a sNaN with a specific payload, I have to create the bit-representation directly/manually.  It is portable if it follows a spec (IEEE-754/ICE-559), and if one can check for that spec via C++ standard APIs ( `numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559` ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no.  If `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559`, then you
know the format of `T`, more or less: you still have to
determine the byte order.  For anything else, all bets are off.
(The other formats I know that are still being used aren't even
base 2: IBM mainframes use base 16, for example.)  The
"standard" arrangement of an IEC floating point has the sign on
the high order bit, then the exponent, and the mantissa on the
low order bits; if you can successfully view it as an
`uint64_t`, for example (via `memcpy`, `reinterpret_cast` or
`union`—`memcpy is guaranteed to work, but is less
efficient than the other two), then:

for `double`:

```
uint64_t tmp;
memcpy( &tmp, &theDouble, sizeof( double ) );
bool isNeg = (tmp & 0x8000000000000000) != 0;
int  exp   = (int)( (tmp & 0x7FF0000000000000) >> 52 ) - 1022 - 53;
long mant  = (tmp & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFF) | 0x0010000000000000;
```

for `float:

```
uint32_t tmp;
memcpy( &tmp, &theFloat, sizeof( float ) );
bool isNeg = (tmp & 0x80000000) != 0;
int  exp   = (int)( (tmp & 0x7F800000) >> 23 ) - 126 - 24 );
long mant  = (tmp & 0x007FFFFF) | 0x00800000;
```

With regards to `long double`, it's worse, because different
compilers treat it differently, even on the same machine. 
Nominally, it's ten bytes, but for alignment reasons, it may in
fact be 12 or 16.  Or just a synonym for `double`.  *If* it's
more than 10 bytes, I *think* you can count on it being packed
into the first 10 bytes, so that `&myLongDouble` gives the
address of the 10 byte value.  But generally speaking, I'd avoid
`long double`.

Comment: I've been tinkering with a `union { unsigned long words[ ( sizeof( T ) -1 ) / sizeof(unsigned long) + 1]; T value; };` to inspect the bits.

Comment: Yes, I've read that 'long double' is actually 'double' on Windows 64-bit.  On my GNU/Linux 64-bit, it has the +2 packing-bytes to get to 12-bytes.

Comment: Heh, "just don't bother for `long double`"; I hadn't seriously considered that before.  For `float` and `double`, if not `is_iec559`, I don't try to pack the significand with a bit-pattern; I could ignore packing the significand for `long double`, no matter the `is_iec559`ness.

Comment: @CharlesLWilcox That's a strange union.  The classical union would be something like: `union { unsigned char image[ sizeof(T) ]; T value }'.  This still means that even on platforms with IEC, you have to consider endianness.  Since IEC guarantees that `double` is 64 bits, and is not implemented on any platform which doesn't have `uint64_t`, those are the two types I'd alias.  As for how to alias: `memcpy` works everywhere (but is usually significantly slower); the `union` or the `reinterpret_cast` will normally work in specific situations, but require more care.

Comment: I was using `unsigned long` as a guess for the native word-size, for faster math.  ( `std::bitset` on GNU/Linux happens to use this, and I was looking at that around the same time. )  Yes, the `uint8_t chars[ sizeof(T) ]` would be much more explicit / straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the only portable way is to store the number as a string. This is not relying on "interpreting bit patterns"

Even if you know how many bits something is, doesn't mean that it has the same representation - the exponent zero-based or biased. Is there an invisible 1 at the front of the mantissa? The same applies to all of the other parts of the number. And it gets even worse for BCD encoded or "hexadecimal" floats - these are available in some architectures...

If you are worried about uninitialized bits in a structure (class, array, etc), then use memset to set the entire structure to zero [or some other known value].

Comment: + mantissa representation (2's complement or sign-magnitude), special values (INFINITY, NAN), subnormal values, order of bits. And there may be some more intricacies.

Comment: I really don't want to serialize to/from string just to set a specific value, and test for that value in other `T`'s later on.  (Also, setting a signaling-NaN value via `scanf` or `operator>>` may not be portable.)  I need to write a function to test for this pattern in a user's `T`; `memset`ing a local `T`, assigning the user-value to the local, then inspecting the bits seems a bit over-complicated.

Comment: Um, a generic solution is going to be even more complicated. Why not develop a platform-specific solution instead and include a check to see that this is the right platform?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Thus my preconditions of floats really being IEEE754/IEC559, and the radix really being '2'.
I'm writing a small library; useful libraries are portable.

Comment: @CharlesLWilcox If the floats are IEC, then the radix must be 2.

Comment: @JamesKanze Ahh, thanks.  I was being a bit sloppy in not verifying that.  :-)

Comment: @JamesKanze - well, yes, but at this point that's hyper-technical. IEC-559 has been merged into IEEE-754, and IEEE-754 as of 2008 provides **both** binary and decimal floating-point. Unfortunately, the C++ standard chose the wrong name for `numeric_limits::is_iec559`.

Comment: @JamesKanze - a little followup: I left out ISO/IEC 60559, which was most recently revised in 2011, and is, apparently, identical to IEEE 754.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, but do you know of a platform where IEC double is decimal?  (I had, in fact, forgotten that possibility, because I've never actually seen it.)

Comment: @JamesKanze - not specifically, but IBM **really** liked decimal floating point. Hence the TR, which is now being considered for incorporation into the C++ standard.

Comment: @Pete Probably because IBM produces hardware with decimal FPUs.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, this is what I ended up doing.

To generate and test for my IEEE-754 signaling-NaN values, I use this pattern for 'float' and 'double'.

```
#include <cstdint> // uint32_t, uint64_t
#include <limits> // numeric_limits

union IEEE754_Float_Union
{
    float value;
    uint32_t bits;
};

float generate_IEEE754_float()
{
    IEEE754_Float_Union u = { -std::numeric_limits< float >::signaling_NaN() };
    size_t const num_significand_bits_to_set = std::numeric_limits< float >::digits
                                               - 1 // implicit "integer-bit"
                                               - 1; // the "signaling-bit"
    u.bits |= ( static_cast< uint32_t >( 1 ) << num_significand_bits_to_set ) - 1;
    return u.value;
}

bool test_IEEE754_float( float const& a_r_val )
{
    IEEE754_Float_Union const u = { a_r_val };
    IEEE754_Float_Union const expected_u = { generate_IEEE754_float() };
    return u.bits == expected_u.bits;
}
```

For 'long double', I use the 'double' functions with casting.  Specifically, I generate the 'double' value and cast it to 'long double' before it's returned, and I test the 'long double' by casting to 'double' then testing that value.  My idea is that, while the 'long double' format can vary, casting a 'double' into a 'long double', then casting it back to 'double' later on should be consistent, ( i.e. not loose any information. )

Comment: Just FYI, this violates the strict aliasing rule of C++. It should "probably" work in any compiler that also supports standard C, though. Just don't be surprised if it doesn't.