# Correct way of reading bytes from IEEE754 floating point format

Tags: c, floating-point, byte, ieee-754

I have a requirement where I need to read the 4 raw bytes of the **single precision IEEE754 floating point** representation as to send on the serial port as it is without any modification. I just wanted to ask what is the correct way of extracting the bytes among the following:

1.) creating a union such as:

```
typedef union {
  float f;
  uint8_t bytes[4];
  struct {
    uint32_t mantissa : 23;
    uint32_t exponent : 8;
    uint32_t sign : 1;
  };
} FloatingPointIEEE754_t ;
```

and then just reading the `bytes[]` array after writing to the float variable `f`?

2.) Or, extracting bytes by a function in which a `uint32_t` type pointer is made to point to the `float` variable and then the bytes are extracted via masking

```
uint32_t extractBitsFloat(float numToExtFrom, uint8_t numOfBits, uint8_t bitPosStartLSB){
  uint32_t *p = &numToExtFrom;
  /* validate the inputs */
  if ((numOfBits > 32) || (bitPosStartLSB > 31)) return NULL;
  /* build the mask */
  uint32_t mask = ((1 << numOfBits) - 1) << bitPosStartLSB;
  return ((*p & mask) >> bitPosStartLSB);
}
```

where calling will be made like:

```
valF = -4.235;
byte0 = extractBitsFloat(valF, 8, 0);
byte1 = extractBitsFloat(valF, 8, 8);
byte2 = extractBitsFloat(valF, 8, 16);
byte3 = extractBitsFloat(valF, 8, 24);
```

Please suggest me the correct way if you think both the above-mentioned methods are wrong!

Comment: Your second method violates the strict aliasing rule. You could us a char pointer instead.

Comment: You say that you want to extract 4 bytes so it's unclear to me why you operate at bit level. Please clarify.

Comment: Actually, that I just put a generic function to extract any bit /word location from the float?

Comment: Beware of endianness. Your methods could not return bytes in the same order. Anyway the standard enforces the use of a character pointer to access the bytes of the representation of any type.

Comment: And using bit fields in an union only guarantees that you cannot know how an implementation will map the bits... Please don't.

Comment: If endianness is important for your use case, have a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620601/portable-serialisation-of-ieee754-floating-point-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I assume you're coding specifically for a platform where `float` actually **is** represented in a IEEE754 *single*. You can't take this for granted *in general*, so your code won't be portable to all platforms.

Then, the `union` approach is the correct one. But don't add this bitfield member! There's no guarantee how the bits will be arranged, so you might access the wrong bits. Just do this:

```
typedef union {
  float f;
  uint8_t bytes[4];
} FloatingPointIEEE754;
```

Also, don't add a `_t` suffix to your own types. On POSIX systems, this is reserved to the implementation, so it's best to always avoid it.

Instead of using a `union`, accessing the bytes through a `char` pointer is fine as well:

```
unsigned char *rep = (unsigned char *)&f;
// access rep[0] to rep[3]
```

Note in both cases, you are accessing the representation in memory, this means you have to pay attention to the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your machine.

---

Your second option isn't correct, it violates the *strict aliasing rule*. In short, you're not allowed to access an object through a pointer that doesn't have compatible type, a `char` pointer is an explicit exception for accessing the representation. The exact rules are written in [6.5 p7 of N1570](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7), the latest draft to the C11 standard.

Comment: is there a way to command the compiler to arrange the bits in a specific order? just curious!

Comment: No. Of course, a compiler could provide some extension, but that's not covered by the standard. The use-case for bitfields is to conserve space, so they are *mostly* useless nowadays.

Comment: How do you suggest should I reframe the function extractBitsFloat() if I have to do bitmasking and extracting bit/bytes at certain locations in the 32-bit float type, without violating the strict aliasing rule? Because after creating the mask, I have to AND it with the 32-bit number itself, how can I do this when using char pointer for accessing the float representation?

Comment: @Akay you can for example `memcpy()` to an `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&the_float;
```

and then read 4 bytes from where `p` is pointing (e.g. `p[0]`, `p[1]`, etc.).  The exact best code to "read 4 bytes" depends on what form the serial port function accepts data in.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care of endianness, just alias a character pointer to the address of a float. The standard explicitely allows to use a charater pointer to access the bytes of the representation of any type. If you need a specific endianness to send the bytes on the serial port, you can test for it before sending:

1. Simple way, just use native endianness:

   ```
   float f;
   ...
   char * bytes = &f;       // bytes point the the beginning of a char array of size sizeof(f)
   ```
2. Automatically test for endianness and uses big endian (AKA network order). The `struct` is just a trick to return an array and have thread safe code.

   ```
   struct float_bytes {
       char bytes[sizeof(float)];
   };
   struct float_bytes(float f) {
       float end = 1.;
       float_bytes resul;
       char *src = (char *) &f;
       if (*end == 0) {                // end is 0 on a little endian platform, else 0x3f
           int i = sizeof(f) {         // little endian: reverse the bytes
           while (i > 0) {
               resul.bytes[--i] = src++;
           }
       }
       else {                          // already in big endian order, just memcpy
           memcpy(&(resul.bytes), &f, sizeof(f));
       }
       return resul;
   }
   ```

   Beware: the test for endianness will only make sense if floating point is IEEE754 single.

Comment: The worth of the endian test is not definitive here. The endian that needs assessment is the endian of the `float`, not of an `int`.

Comment: Further, are you certain of the `int` endian test?   I'd expect `if (end != 1)`,  With `*((char*) &end) = 1;`, `(end != 0)` should be true regardless of endian.

Comment: @chux: Might I have forgotten a star? ;-). And you are right, I should test floating point endianness. Edited