# Convert between little-endian and big-endian floats effectively

Tags: c++, boost, endianness

I have a working software, which currently runs on a `little-endian` architecture. I would like to make it run in `big-endian` mode too. I would like to write `little-endian` data into files, regardless of the endianness of the underlying system.

To achieve this, I decided to use the boost endian library. It can convert integers efficiently. But it cannot handle floats (and doubles).

It states in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/endian/doc/index.html), that "*Floating point types will be supported in the Boost 1.59.0*". But they are still not supported in `1.62`.

I can assume, that the floats are valid `IEEE 754` floats (or doubles). But their endianness may vary according to the underlying system. As far as I know, using the `htonl` and `ntohl` functions on floats is not recommended. How is it possible then? Is there any header-only library, which can handle floats too? I was not able to find any.

I could convert the floats to string, and write that into a file, I would like to avoid that method, for many reasons ( performance, disk-space, ... )

Comment: No need for any lib, it's pretty immediate. Have a look there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782725/converting-float-values-from-big-endian-to-little-endian

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
float f = 1.2f;
auto it = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&f);
std::reverse(it, it + sizeof(f)); //f is now in the reversed endianness
```

No need for anything fancy.

Answer (score 1):

Unheilig: you are correct, but

```
#include <boost/endian/conversion.hpp>


template <typename T>
inline T endian_cast(const T & t)
{
#ifdef BOOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN
    return boost::endian::endian_reverse(t);
#else
    return t;
#endif
}
```

or when u are using pointers, to immediate reversing, use:

```
template <typename T>
inline T endian_cast(T *t)
{
#ifdef BOOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN
    return boost::endian::endian_reverse_inplace(*t);
#else
    return t;
#endif
}
```

and use it, instead of manually (or maybe error-prone) reversing it's content

example:

```
std::uint16_t start_address() const
{
    std::uint16_t address;
    std::memcpy(&address, &data()[1], 2);
    return endian_cast(address);
}
void start_address(std::uint16_t i)
{
    endian_cast(&i);
    std::memcpy(&data()[1], &i, 2);
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: No overload for floats [1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/endian/doc/conversion.html). but one still need to force reversing the endian

Answer (score 1):

When serializing float/double values, I make the following three assumptions:

1. The machine representation follows IEEE 754
2. The endianess of float/double matches the endianess of integers
3. The behavior of reinterpret_cast-ing between double&/int64_t& or float&/int32_t& is well-defined (E.g., the cast behaves as if the types are similar).

None of these assumptions is guaranteed by the standard.  Under these assumptions, the following code will ensure doubles are written in little-endian:

```
ostream out;
double someVal;
...
static_assert(sizeof(someVal) == sizeof(int64_t),
    "Endian conversion requires 8-byte doubles");
native_to_little_inplace(reinterpret_cast<int64_t&>(someVal));
out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&someVal), sizeof(someVal));
```

Comment: I probably should have added that `boost::endian::native_to_little_inplace` is defined in *boost/endian/conversion.hpp*.