# Compile time/macro swap of endianess of float in c99

Tags: c, macros, c99

I have some floats (IEEE-754) that I want to initialize. The floats are fetched by another device (automagically) which runs big endian where I am using little endian and I can't change that.

Normally I would just swap with some built in function, but they are all run-time functions. I'd perfer not having to have an init() function just to swap endianess and it would be great if I could use it for `const` initializations also.

Something that result in this would be perfect:

`#define COMPILE_TIME_SWAPPED_FLOAT(x) (...)
const float a = COMPILE_TIME_SWAPPED_FLOAT(1.0f);`

Any great ideas?

Comment: You say "fetched by another device" but then you have `1.0f` hardcoded in your code. Please clarify what is going on

Comment: My guess would be that even if you didn't use a macro most reasonable optimizing compilers would still be able to do this optimization at compile time. Of course you should check the compiler output to confirm.

Comment: In this particular case, it is a constant timeout for a watchdog for this particular device, which the remote system wants to know (for unknown reasons). The remote system request the data over a RS485 bus and expects the data to be in a certain endianess.

Comment: Instead of "fetched by another device" you should say "passed to another device"

Comment: If you're still interested in a compile time approach for a limited range of values (approx. 1e-1 to 1e3), I could come up with one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Compile time/macro swap of endian-ness of float in c99

OP has other problem with using  "reverse" `float` as a `float`

A local variable of type `float` encoding the "reverse" endian floating point value cannot certainly be initialized as a `float`.  Many of the values in reverse byte order would correspond to a Not-A-Number (NAN) in the local `float`.  The assignment may not be stable (bit pattern preserving). It could be:

```
// not a good plan
float f1 = some_particulate_not_a_number_bit_pattern;
float f2 = some_other_particulate_not_a_number_bit_pattern;
```

Instead the local "reversed" endian `float` should just be a `uint32_t`, 4-byte structure/union or 4-byte array initialized in some way with a `float`.

```
// Demo of why a reversed `float` can fail
// The Not-a-numbers bit to control signaling NaN vs. quiet NaN isn't certainly preserved. 

int main(void) {
  for (;;) {
    union {
      int32_t i32;
      int32_t u32;
      float f;
    } x,y;
    x.i32 = rand();
    y.f = x.f;
    if (x.u32 ^ y.u32) {
      // If bit pattern preserved, this should never print
      //                                 v-------+---- biased exponent max (NaN)
      //                                 |-------|v--- signaling/quiet bit
      // On my machine output is always x1111111 1?xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
      printf("%08x\n",   (unsigned) x.u32);
      printf("%08x\n\n", (unsigned) y.u32);
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
7f8181b1
7fc181b1
...
```

---

The below uses a *compound literal* to meet OP's goal.  First initialize a union's `float` member with the desired `float`.  Then extract it byte-by-byte from its `uint8_t` member (per desired endian) to initialize a new  *compound literal's* `uint8_t` array member.  Then extract the `uint32_t`.  Works for local variables.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef uint32_t float_reversed;

typedef union  {
  uint8_t u8[4];
  float_reversed u32;
  float f;
} endian_f;

#define ENDIAN_FN(_f,_n)  ( (endian_f){.f=(_f)}.u8[(_n)] )
#define ENDIAN_F(_f) ((endian_f){ \
    ENDIAN_FN(_f,3), ENDIAN_FN(_f,2), \
    ENDIAN_FN(_f,1), ENDIAN_FN(_f,0)}.u32)

void print_hexf(void *f) {
  for (size_t i=0; i<sizeof f; i++) {
    printf("%02X", ((unsigned char *)f)[i]);
  }
  puts("");
}

int main(void) {
  float f1 = 1.0f;
  print_hexf(&f1);

  float_reversed f1r = ENDIAN_F(f1);
  print_hexf(&f1r);
  float_reversed f2r = ENDIAN_F(1.0);
  print_hexf(&f2r);
}
```

Output

```
0000803F
3F800000
3F800000
```

Comment: Unfortunately the requirement is to have this working in global scope, which it won't I suspect.

Comment: @Armali Post ammended

Comment: Ok, its does not seem to be requirement, but still it "*won't work*" on global scope, right? ;-)

Comment: @alk I see no global scope variable solution yet.  Hence this answer's "Works for local variables."

Comment: Excellent answer! I was looking for a union initializer, but compound literal expressions are the right way to destructure the bitwise representation. I am not sure if this approach has 100% defined behavior because type-punning via `union`s still confuses me. How come no-one else voted this up?

Comment: @chqrlie _Compound literals_ from C99 are still new-ish and have sluggish wide acceptance.  Using a `union` through an `unsigned char[]` is quite well defined as there are no trap, padding  nor aliasing issues.

Comment: It is a pity acceptance is so slow, probably because they are not part of even recent C++ releases. Also beats be why your solution cannot be used for global scope. It is about time one could use more expressivity at global scope without ugly macros.

Comment: @chqrlie   Hmmmm: at global scope, C allows `endian_f x1 = { .f = 3.14f };` - no surprise.  gcc warns about `endian_f x2 = (endian_f ) { .f = 3.14f };` - a small surprise yet fails `float f1 = (endian_f ) { .f = 3.14f } .f;`.

Comment: It is not done compile time, but I think it is the closest we are going to get.

Comment: @Tajen With code like `float_reversed f1r = ENDIAN_F(f1);` C does not specify that this code must be computed at compile time nor does it specify that it must be done at run time.  An optimizing compile will certainly make for efficient code.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say having the preprocessor to swap bytes of some non byte variable isn't possible.

The preprocessor does not know about data types and their representation on byte-level.

Comment: Would you say that any swapping of bytes is impossible by the preprocessor?

Comment: @Tajen:  If you'd pass it bytes it might be able to swap them, but it cannot parse any other data type into bytes, and then swap those. Answer adjusted.

Comment: I could convert the float value to a uint32_t hex value and also swap it myself. but then I need the preprocessor to copy it to the float without converting it.
That should be possible - in theory at least.

Comment: @Tajen: This might work at run-time, but won't during compilation, which is a prerequisite to have this work on global scope.

Answer (score 0):

If the endian reversal code is available to be inlined then any half decent optimizing compiler will work out the reversed value at compile time.

Taking the reversal code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2782742/2348315 :

```
inline float ReverseFloat( const float inFloat )
{
   float retVal;
   char *floatToConvert = ( char* ) & inFloat;
   char *returnFloat = ( char* ) & retVal;

   // swap the bytes into a temporary buffer
   returnFloat[0] = floatToConvert[3];
   returnFloat[1] = floatToConvert[2];
   returnFloat[2] = floatToConvert[1];
   returnFloat[3] = floatToConvert[0];

   return retVal;
}
```

And using it in away that compiler can see all the details:

```
float reversed10(){
  const float reversed = ReverseFloat(10.0f);
  return reversed;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
reversed10():
        vmovss  xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   8257
```

with GCC 7.1 with -O2 enabled.

You can try other compilers over here:
https://godbolt.org/g/rFmJGP

Comment: Thanks @Armali I've corrected to the correct C syntax.

Comment: A corner problem with `float reversed = ReverseFloat(10.0f)` is that the return from `ReverseFloat()` may be a [signaling Not-a-number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18118408/2410359) and cause problems with the assignment or perhaps even in `return retVal;`