# Reading IBM floating-point in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, binaryfiles, binaryreader, fileparsing

I have a a binary file format with a bunch of headers and floating point data. I am working on a code that parses the binary file. Reading the headers was not hard but when I tried to read the data I ran into some difficulties.

I opened the file and read the headers as the following:

```
ifs.open(fileName, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
char textHeader[3200];
BinaryHeader binaryHeader;
ifs.read(textHeader,sizeof(textHeader));
ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&binaryHeader), sizeof(binaryHeader));
```

The documentation says the data is stored as: **4-byte IBM floating-point** and I tried something similar:

```
vector<float> readData(int sampleSize){
    float tmp;
    std::vector<float> tmpVector;
    for (int i = 0; i<sampleSize; i++){
        ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tmp), sizeof(tmp));
        std::cout << tmp << std::endl;
        tmpVector.push_back(tmp);
    }
    return tmpVector;
}
```

Sadly the result does not seem correct. What do I do wrong?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, the binary data is in big-endian, but if I print the tmp values out the data does not seem correct either way.

> Conclusion: The **4-byte IBM floating-point** is not the same as the
>   float.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly, but at first glance there might be two issues that I can see. First you have an array of char for your header, this might be okay, but have you tried using an unsigned char instead? The second possible issue is that in your `readData()` function you create a temporary vector on that functions stack frame and you then return it. Maybe try changing the signature of this function to accept an `std::vector<float>` by reference and pass it into the function instead of return a copy to a temporary.

Comment: Is the binary data big or little endian?

Comment: @RetiredNinja That's a good question to the OP, that would make a huge difference too!

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Forgot to mention all the values is the header is in big-endian.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782725/converting-float-values-from-big-endian-to-little-endian

Comment: “4-byte IBM floating-point” is probably not the same as `float`. If that’s the case You’ll have to do some work to translate the input into something your hardware can work with.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was afraid of. Thank you!

Comment: This may be the format: https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nssdc/formats/IBM_32-Bit.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_hexadecimal_floating_point

Comment: Google “4-byte IBM floating-point”. There’s lots of information out there. And, as I guessed earlier, it’s not the same layout as an IEEE float.

Comment: Can you post one example output of `std::cout << std::hex << (int&)(tmp) << std::endl;`

Comment: Yes, I got this:
33331341
3d331341
48331341
52331341
5d331341
67331341
72331341
7c331341
87331341
91331341
9c331341
a6331341
b1331341
bb331341
c6331341
d0331341
db331341
e5331341
f0331341
fa331341
4341341
f341341
19341341
24341341
2e341341
39341341
43341341
4e341341
58341341
63341341
6d341341
78341341
82341341
8d341341
97341341
a2341341
ac341341
b7341341
c1341341
cc341341
d6341341
e1341341
eb341341
f6341341

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider:

- The first one, I'm not 100% sure if this would make a difference or not, but you are using an array of chars for your header `char textHeader[3200];`. Maybe you could try changing this to an array of `unsigned char` instead...
- The second one in which I think may be a bigger issue which has to do more with performance is within your `readData` function itself. You are creating a local temporary `std::vector` of `floats` on that functions stack frame. Then you are returning it. The return isn't even by reference or pointer so this will also create unnecessary copies, however by the time the next piece of code tries to use this vector, the temporary has already been destroyed since the function has already gone out of scope. For this issue I would probably suggest changing the declaration and definition of this function.

  I would change it from what you currently have:

  > `vector<float> readData(int sampleSize)`

  to this:

  > `void readData( int sampleSizes, std::vector<float>& data )`

- The third which is probably the most important of the three was mentioned in a form of a question in your comments by user `RetiredNinja` as I was originally writing this, had asked you a very good question about the endian of the data type being stored. This can also be a major factor. The actual data representation that is physically stored in memory I think is the biggest concern here.

---

According to the fact that your documentation has stated that it is stored as a 4-byte IBM floating-point type and that it is in big endian; I have found this [specification](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1018038) by IBM that may be of help to you.

Comment: Thank you! I think the biggest problem as  Pete Becker mentioned, the float and the 4-byte IBM floating-point is not the same. The data is in big-endian I have a function that converts it to little-endian but the result is not correct either way.

Comment: There’s nothing inherently wrong with returning a vector by value. And the problem doesn’t occur when reading the header, so making it unsigned won’t help.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah I wasn't 100% sure, but mentioned it just incase. However, I still think the returning of vector by a local temp is just not favorable coding design, with large containers that are being filled with data or its contents being manipulated, I tend to prefer to pass them in to the functions by reference. However, the biggest issue I think is the actual representation of the data in memory itself.

Comment: Well, that may be reasonable style advice, but it won’t fix the problem.

Comment: @PeteBecker I reworded my answer to reflect on that more.