# Byte Array to Double Conversion fails in QT

Tags: c#, c++, qt, double, byte

When I convert following bytes which are received from TCP communication, I get 0 in QT and 32.097133442517112 in C#.NET. How can I resolve this issue in QT?

C# .NET

```
byte[] data = {0xbd, 0x7a, 0x5f, 0xde, 0x6e, 0x0c, 0x40, 0x40};
double value = BitConverter.ToDouble(data, 0); // value is 32.097133442517112
```

C++ QT

```
QByteArray *arr = new QByteArray();
arr->append(0xbd);
arr->append(0x7a);
arr->append(0x5f);
arr->append(0xde);
arr->append(0x6e);
arr->append(0x0c);
arr->append(0x40);
arr->append(0x40);
double value = arr->toDouble(); // value is 0
```

**EDIT:**
Following snippet seems to work ok. It gives the result as 32.0971.

```
union {
    double d;
    char bytes[sizeof(double)];
} u;

u.bytes[0]=0xbd;
u.bytes[1]= 0x7a;
u.bytes[2]=0x5f;
u.bytes[3]=0xde;
u.bytes[4]=0x6e;
u.bytes[5]=0x0c;
u.bytes[6]= 0x40;
u.bytes[7]=0x40;
qDebug()<<u.d; // result 32.0971
```

Should I continue with this, or are there any QT side solution for that?

Comment: @Ian It outputs again 0 when I reversed the bytes in array.

Comment: @Ian I have QByteArray and want the number value. However QByteArray::number gets a number and returns as QByteArray. I didn't get the point.

Comment: @Ian Tried with both QByteArray dbl("BD7A5FDE6E0C4040") and QByteArray dbl("40400C6EDE5F7ABD")  and the same result, success is false, return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, QDataStream does it:

```
double value2;
QDataStream stream(*arr);
stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
stream >> value2; // value2 is 32.097133442517112
```

Thanks for those who contributed.

Comment: Cast does it too: `double value = *( double*)(arr->constData());`

Comment: @Ilya Yes, confirmed!

Answer (score 0):

i think the `QByteArray::toDouble()` does only work for readable double values (like 3.14) so [Converting char * to double while reading from binary file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060910/converting-char-to-double-while-reading-from-binary-file-in-c) should give you a hint on how it could be done