# Convert text file with numbers to binary

Tags: binary, ascii

I have a text file with double precision numbers. The numbers are separated by newline characters.

```
1.58589
0.04151
0.03562
0.02866
0.04479
0.01562
0.0219
0.01162
0.0089
0.0123
0.00621
-0.0135
-0.0046
-0.01052
-0.00873
0.0018
0.00436
....
```

How can I convert this into a binary file with default (system) endianness?

---

Edit:

I do not want to compress the file, just make sure that the doubles are stored consecutively without any additional information (header etc.) in the file.

To goal is to be able to read the file direcly into memory later and do a reinterpret cast to have a `double*` array (e.g. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6789856/3867787)).

---

Edit 2: 
[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149187/convert-file-with-integers-written-in-ascii-to-binary-file-of-integers?rq=1) asks the same thing for integers, which is easier since the binary representation is simpler.

---

Edit 3: 
using schaiba's hint it is possible to convert 666.42 into a binary number:

```
echo "obase=2;666.42" | bc
1010011010.011010
```

But this contains a dot symbol. I am not sure how to write this into a file.

Comment: Pointer : `echo "obase=2;$number" | bc`

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "with default (system) endianness". There are many possible interpretations, and it all depends on what you are planning to do with the binary file later on.

Comment: @Alexander i added more explanation.

Comment: What do you exactly mean under "convert into a binary file"? Can you provide an example output of some kind?

Comment: @schaiba How do I deal with the dot in the output? Please see edit 3.

Comment: this sound like an XY-problem, what do you mean by : to read the file direcly into memory ? c function scanf should do just fine.

Comment: This is a very straightforward question and was in the first revision. It's asking to convert a file of textual floating-point numbers to contiguous native-endian IEEE754 binary64.

Comment: Indeed. The OP is asking to convert floatingpoint numbers in textual representation into machine readable format. @schaiba, @Beginner: This is not about using `bc`. You probably need to write a program for this; thus, I vote to move this question to StackOverflow.

Comment: @countermode This question was on-topic at [unix.se] and **should not** have been migrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward way is probably to use [Perl's `pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html):

```
perl -e 'while(<>) {print(pack "d", $_)}'
```

or equivalently

```
perl -pe '$_ = pack "d", $_'
```

. `d` means

> A double-precision float in native format.

and `print` has no trailing newline by default, so this will output eight-byte blocks corresponding to each line read from standard input. Several languages have similar features but `perl` should be everywhere.

Comment: is there a similary way to get the original text file back from the binary?

Comment: @Beginner would you believe ... [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html)