# Divide a float into single bytes

Tags: c++, networking

I am using RakNet for networking and I need to transmit float values. The problem is, that I can only send single bytes. 
Since float is composed out of 4 bytes, I thought it must be possible, to tear the float down into these four bytes and send them. After that, I want to compose them together again to a float.

How do I do that?

Comment: pointers and pointer math... get the address of the float, then start sucking bytes.

Comment: Be careful about big vs little endian as well

Comment: You could serialize it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786137/c-serialization-of-the-floating-point-numbers-floats-doubles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `memcpy` the original `float` value to an appropriately sized array of `unsigned char`s

   ```
   float f = ...;

   unsigned char c[sizeof f];
   memcpy(c, &f, sizeof f);
   // use `c[i]` to access the bytes
   ```
2. Reinterpret the original pointer as an array of `unsigned char`s using `reinterpret_cast`

   ```
   float f = ...;

   unsigned char *c = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&f);
   // use `c[i]` to access the bytes
   ```
3. Use a union to perform the same reinterpretation

   ```
   union FC {
     float f;
     unsigned char c[sizeof FC::f];
   };

   float f = ...;

   FC u = { f };
   // use `u.c[i]` to access the bytes
   ```

Just keep in mind a few extra details: the last approach (with `union`) is now legal in C, but is still formally illegal in C++ - you are not allowed to read "inactive" members of unions in C++. Observe the byte ordering on little- vs. big-endian platforms. If you use the second approach, also reinterpret the recipient `float` as an array of `unsigned char`s and not the other way around to avoid alignment issues.

Comment: I wouldn't use memcpy function because it is a very risky function from the point of view of security. ;)

Comment: @NKN: There's nothing risky about it if you know what you are doing. "Risky" functions are the functions that do not offer you any chance to prevent problems (like `gets` or `atoi`, for example). `memcpy` does not belong to that category.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first method sounds like the easiest. 
But how do you make a float again out of these bytes?

Comment: @Liess Jemai: In the first method, you just `memcpy` it back from char array to a `float` object. In the second method... well, you have to be careful: reinterpret the target `float` object as an array of char and write the data there. In the third method, you simply do it backwards: store the bytes into `u.c` and then read `u.f`.

Comment: @zhiayang: Reinterpreting char array as a float is not a good idea: it does not guarantee that the alignment requirements are met and it is generally illegal.