# Binary serialization of floating point numbers (restricted to IPC)

Tags: c++, c, serialization, floating-point, ipc

I have two processes running on the *same device* (no VMs involved), communicating over a binary IPC protocol. Since this guarantees that the the representation of the number is the same for the sender and the receiver, can I safely assume that the following serialization will work on any device that supports floating point numbers?

```
void store_double(uint8_t *buf, double d)
{
    memcpy(buf, &d, sizeof(double));
}

double load_double(uint8_t const *buf)
{
    double d;
    memcpy(&d, buf, sizeof(double));
    return d;
}

double orig = 123.456;
uint8_t serialized[sizeof(double)];
store_double(serialized, orig);
// send serialized bytes to the receiver

// receive serialized bytes from the sender
double copy = load_double(serialized);
```

Comment: As your restrict your environment to avoid endianness issues, I would say it is safe (as long as `buf` is long enough, which is your case).

Comment: Endian issues shouldn't matter if the hardware on both ends represents `double` values in IEEE double format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 1):

Since the sender and the receiver are identical architectures, there are no endian issues, floating point, integer, or otherwise.

If the architectures are different, you might have problems.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786137/c-serialization-of-the-floating-point-numbers-floats-doubles) or this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782725/converting-float-values-from-big-endian-to-little-endian/2782742#2782742).