# How to write a double value in a file, without knowing its precision ofstream

Tags: c++

I am learning c++. I don't understand how to write a long double value in a file.
I don't know the number of decimals values, so i think i can't use setprecision. Can you show me hints?

Because this subject is for me a way to understand basic c++, i should only use 
`iostream` and `fstream`.

I don't understand why ofstream decide to truncate my number

```
long double number=0.12345678987654321012345678987654321012 ..etc;

ofstream myfile("name.txt", ios::binary);

myfile << number ;
```

It write only 0.1234

Things i tried so far:

```
myfile << number ;
```

and

```
    char     *conversion = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&number );
    myfile << *(reinterpret_cast<double *>(conversion));
    myfile .close();
```

and

```
    myfile.write((char *)&resultat, sizeof(long double))  ;
```

Comment: Why can't you just use `std::setprecision` with a suitably large number? Say `20` or `30`? Whatever precision you need.

Comment: @Galik this is not an answer because it will write excess zeros also. More, you can't guarantee that 20 or 30 is large enough to fit.

Comment: I'm not sure that it will write excess zeros. Did you try it? But can't you just pick the precision that your application requires? Or what about using [std::numeric_limits/digits10](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1786137/1938163

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution can be based on numeric limits. You are storing your data in `double` so use it's numeric limits.

```
myfile << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 2) << number
```

Comment: this is a static limit, if i understand rigth, it's 12 digits. How could i set it dynamicly?

Comment: Why do you need that? It is a limit that can contain `double` at all. if you store your data in `double` you don't need any more. Also, this will delete excess zeros and you will get proper value.

Comment: I need that because i'm calculating approximations of Pi. I don't know how much precision i'll need, but it's around thousands.

Comment: You don't have "thousands of digits" of precision in a double, or in a long double. There's no point writing out more digits than the representation can hold, and `std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10` tells you how many digits that would be.